# I need to arrange this code in a way i can call it from anywhere

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript function that runs immediately after the DOM loads. It tries to get the element of the drag-drop field although it is not yet available resulting to a null error. Therefore i am unable to use this function if my drag-drop is a modal or in any other page that does not load when the system starts.

My current solution is to load a hidden drag drop field but I need a more flexible solution where I can implement it from anywhere. I need to stop it from running immediately the website loads and trigger it through an event like on drop or on load in such a way it will run the whole of it. I have tried to rearrange it but the code is too messed up hence thought the original one would be easy for you to understand. I know jquery is easier but am in a situation where i need to use vanilla javascript

```
(function() {

  // getElementById
  function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  // file drag hover
  function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
  }


  // file selection
  function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      UploadFile(f);
    }

  }



  // output file information
  function ParseFile(file) {

    var iconpath = "";
    var size = 0;
    var units = "";

    if (file.type == "application/pdf") {
      iconpath = "<img src='resources/dragdrop/pdf.png' style='width:50px;height:50px;'>";
    } else {
      iconpath = "File Information:";
    }

    if (file.size > 1048576) {
      size = file.size / 1024 / 1024;
      units = "MB";
    } else {
      size = file.size / 1024;
      units = "KB";
    }


    return "<td class='dragtd'>" + iconpath + "</td><td class='dragtd'>" + file.name + "</td><td class='dragtd'>" + file.type + "<td class='dragtd'>" + size.toFixed(2) + "" + units + "</td>";
  }


  // upload JPEG files
  function UploadFile(file) {

    // following line is not necessary: prevents running on SitePoint servers
    if (location.host.indexOf("sitepointstatic") >= 0)
      return

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {

      // create progress bar
      var o = $id("messages");
      var k = $id("progress");
      var step = k.appendChild(document.createElement("z"));
      var content = o.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
      var progress = k.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
      progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Waiting to upload"));
      // progress bar
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",
        function(e) {
          var pc = parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
          progress.style.width = pc + "%";
          progress.innerHTML = pc + "% " + file.name;
          if (pc == 100) {
            content.innerHTML = ParseFile(file);
            k.removeChild(progress);
          } else {

          }
        },
        false
      );

      // file received/failed
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
          progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
        }
      };
      //make multipart
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("thefile", file);

      // start upload
      xhr.open('POST', '/resources/dragdrop/upload.jsp?action=save', true);
      //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        try {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
              var respText = xhr.responseText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
              loadPageInDiv('resources/dragdrop', 'files.jsp', 'fileviewdiv')
            } else {
              alert("error hatujui");
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
        }
      };
      xhr.send(formData);
      ParseFile(file);
    }

  }


  // initialize
  function Init() {

    var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
      filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
      submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

    // file select
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

    // is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {

      // file drop
      filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
      filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
      filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
      filedrag.style.display = "block";

      // remove submit button
      submitbutton.style.display = "none";
    }

  }

  // call initialization file
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
  }


})();
```

Comment: Please make sure your example is a [mcve] (emphasis on _minimal_).

Comment: how about removing the `(function() {` on the first line and the `})();` on the last line?

Comment: I thought a bigger picture of what i am doing is important

Comment: C'mon Nix. StackOverflow is a question and answer site. As such, you are expected to provide one or the other. You've provided neither. Certainly, a question is implied - but it is not asked. We could imagine all day what your precise question is and be wrong for every single guess. Just be explicit, please. :)

Comment: @GeomanYabes yes that would help but will it will leave out some important methods

Comment: @enhzflep let me rethink on my question and will post a better simplified one

Comment: Removing the IIFE will allow these functions to be used elsewhere.